# Safari does not show the svg

Tags: html, svg, svg-animate

I have an svg code in my index.html file but it doesnt appear on Safari. I tryed differend solutions those are not working for me

```html
<svg class="blob" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <svg class="blob" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" style="overflow: visible; filter:blur(18px)"
      >

      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(23, 248, 194);"></stop>
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(78, 50, 195);"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <path fill="url(#gradient)">
        <animate attributeName="d" dur="20000ms" repeatCount="indefinite" animationTimingFunction="ease-out" values="
M441.5,323.5Q425,397,357,435Q289,473,216.5,453.5Q144,434,84,383Q24,332,32,252.5Q40,173,96.5,127.5Q153,82,216.5,81Q280,80,324,115.5Q368,151,413,200.5Q458,250,441.5,323.5Z;
M440.5,315Q405,380,343,402Q281,424,228,402Q175,380,100,356Q25,332,51,259.5Q77,187,117,137.5Q157,88,222.5,62Q288,36,350.5,74.5Q413,113,444.5,181.5Q476,250,440.5,315Z;
M413,307Q386,364,334.5,399Q283,434,210.5,439Q138,444,79.5,388.5Q21,333,61,264.5Q101,196,122.5,131Q144,66,218,39.5Q292,13,359,58Q426,103,433,176.5Q440,250,413,307Z;
M441.5,323.5Q425,397,357,435Q289,473,216.5,453.5Q144,434,84,383Q24,332,32,252.5Q40,173,96.5,127.5Q153,82,216.5,81Q280,80,324,115.5Q368,151,413,200.5Q458,250,441.5,323.5Z;
   
"></animate>
      </path>
    </svg>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(23, 248, 194);"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(78, 50, 195);"></stop>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <path fill="url(#gradient)">
      <animate attributeName="d" dur="20000ms" repeatCount="indefinite" animationTimingFunction="ease-out" values="
M441.5,323.5Q425,397,357,435Q289,473,216.5,453.5Q144,434,84,383Q24,332,32,252.5Q40,173,96.5,127.5Q153,82,216.5,81Q280,80,324,115.5Q368,151,413,200.5Q458,250,441.5,323.5Z;
M440.5,315Q405,380,343,402Q281,424,228,402Q175,380,100,356Q25,332,51,259.5Q77,187,117,137.5Q157,88,222.5,62Q288,36,350.5,74.5Q413,113,444.5,181.5Q476,250,440.5,315Z;
M413,307Q386,364,334.5,399Q283,434,210.5,439Q138,444,79.5,388.5Q21,333,61,264.5Q101,196,122.5,131Q144,66,218,39.5Q292,13,359,58Q426,103,433,176.5Q440,250,413,307Z;
M441.5,323.5Q425,397,357,435Q289,473,216.5,453.5Q144,434,84,383Q24,332,32,252.5Q40,173,96.5,127.5Q153,82,216.5,81Q280,80,324,115.5Q368,151,413,200.5Q458,250,441.5,323.5Z;
   
"></animate>
    </path>
  </svg>`
```

There should be a small blob animation which changes shape based on svg

Comment: You have some odd duplication in your example where your SVG is nested inside an almost identical SVG. Fixing that (by removing the innner svg element and all its children) does not make things work in Safari though.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert says in the comments, the SVG has a weird duplicate. Looks like you *copy-pasted* some lines inside the same SVG

Cleaned the SVG; Runs just fine in FireFox for me:

```html
<style>
  svg {
    height: 160px;
    overflow: visible; 
    filter: blur(18px);
  }
</style>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color: rgb(23, 248, 194);"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color: rgb(78, 50, 195);"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path fill="url(#gradient)">
    <animate attributeName="d" dur="20000ms" repeatCount="indefinite" animationTimingFunction="ease-out" values="
M441.5,323.5Q425,397,357,435Q289,473,216.5,453.5Q144,434,84,383Q24,332,32,252.5Q40,173,96.5,127.5Q153,82,216.5,81Q280,80,324,115.5Q368,151,413,200.5Q458,250,441.5,323.5Z;
M440.5,315Q405,380,343,402Q281,424,228,402Q175,380,100,356Q25,332,51,259.5Q77,187,117,137.5Q157,88,222.5,62Q288,36,350.5,74.5Q413,113,444.5,181.5Q476,250,440.5,315Z;
M413,307Q386,364,334.5,399Q283,434,210.5,439Q138,444,79.5,388.5Q21,333,61,264.5Q101,196,122.5,131Q144,66,218,39.5Q292,13,359,58Q426,103,433,176.5Q440,250,413,307Z;
M441.5,323.5Q425,397,357,435Q289,473,216.5,453.5Q144,434,84,383Q24,332,32,252.5Q40,173,96.5,127.5Q153,82,216.5,81Q280,80,324,115.5Q368,151,413,200.5Q458,250,441.5,323.5Z">
    </animate>
  </path>
</svg>`
```

Comment: The shadow is missing because filter:blur(18px) has gone from the root element but this version does work in Safari.

Comment: Ah, I missed that ``style=".."``. Added them to the ``<style>``